# Other SqlDataReader need to be closed, althought I've closed any other else

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I've closed all the readers properly haven't I? Every time I trigger the function, it causes an error

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed.

Now I'm really frustated.

What's wrong with my code? Everything seems good.

```
Private Sub Button_EditData_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button_EditData.Click
    FormEnabler()
    Me.TextBox_BranchID.Enabled = False
    Me.Button_AddNew.Enabled = False
    Me.Button_EditData.Enabled = False
    Me.Button_DeleteData.Enabled = False
    Me.Button_Save.Enabled = True
    Me.Button_Cancel.Enabled = True
    Me.Button_ManageThisBranchStock.Enabled = False
    Me.Button_ManageThisBranchEmployee.Enabled = False

    theConnection.Open()

    Dim theEditInputCommand As New SqlCommand
    Dim theEditInputDataReader As SqlDataReader

    theEditInputCommand.Connection = theConnection
    theEditInputCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Branch WHERE BranchID = '" & Me.TextBox_BranchID.Text & "'"
    theEditInputDataReader = theEditInputCommand.ExecuteReader()

    If theEditInputDataReader.Read() Then
        Me.TextBox_Title.Text = theEditInputDataReader.Item("Title")
        Me.RichTextBox_Address.Text = theEditInputDataReader.Item("Address")
        Me.TextBox_ContactNumber.Text = theEditInputDataReader.Item("ContactNo")
        Me.ComboBox_BranchManager.Text = theEditInputDataReader.Item("BranchManager")
        theEditInputDataReader.Close()
    End If

    theConnection.Close()

    theConnection.Open()

    Dim theEditInputBranchManagerCommand As New SqlCommand
    Dim theEditInputBranchManagerDataReader As SqlDataReader
    Dim theEditInputBranchManagerDataTable As New DataTable

    theEditInputBranchManagerCommand.Connection = theConnection
    theEditInputBranchManagerCommand.CommandText = "SELECT EmployeeID FROM AssignmentDetail WHERE BranchID = '" & Me.TextBox_BranchID.Text & "'"
    theEditInputBranchManagerDataReader = theEditInputBranchManagerCommand.ExecuteReader()
    theEditInputBranchManagerDataTable.Load(theEditInputBranchManagerDataReader)

    If theEditInputBranchManagerDataReader.Read() Then
        Me.ComboBox_BranchManager.ValueMember = "EmployeeID"
        Me.ComboBox_BranchManager.DisplayMember = "EmployeeID"
        Me.ComboBox_BranchManager.DataSource = theEditInputBranchManagerDataTable
        theEditInputBranchManagerDataReader.Close()
    Else
        Me.ComboBox_BranchManager.ValueMember = "'-'"
        theEditInputBranchManagerDataReader.Close()
    End If

    theConnection.Close()
End Sub
```

The debugger pointed the errors around here:

```
If theEditInputBranchManagerDataReader.Read() Then
    Me.ComboBox_BranchManager.ValueMember = "EmployeeID"
    Me.ComboBox_BranchManager.DisplayMember = "EmployeeID"
    Me.ComboBox_BranchManager.DataSource = theEditInputBranchManagerDataTable
    theEditInputBranchManagerDataReader.Close()
Else
    Me.ComboBox_BranchManager.ValueMember = "'-'"
    theEditInputBranchManagerDataReader.Close()
End If
```

Comment: You need to read about, understand, and start using parameterized queries before bobby tables comes to visit. http://bobby-tables.com/ This code is wide open to sql injection.

Comment: wtf is bobby table?

Comment: Follow the link. It is a cartoon about sql injection. And your code is a classic example of how this vulnerability works.

Comment: btw, i don't need security lol

Comment: OK...feel free to do what you want but sql injection is a serious issue.

Comment: I have a question over, I'll make the thread.

Comment: <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43414195/insert-multiple-rows-count-based-on-another-table-columns">Over HERE!</a>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For everything that has **IDisposable** you should implement **USING**

```
Using reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
    While reader.Read()
        FPath = reader(0)
    End While
End Using
```

Also make sure to dispose of the reader **.Dispose()** if you don't want to use **USING** finally working with SQL it's always good to use:

```
SqlConnection.ClearPool(con)
```

Comment: Yeah I don't really want to use USING, it's really complicated and confusing.

lol it still didn't work, I use the `.Dispose()` and `SqlConnection.ClearPool(theConnection)`

Comment: I tried the USING method. And there's syntax error for `FPath = theDataReader(0)`. My VS didn't recognize that code.

Comment: @BidiAjin Using is very simple just declare Using myvariable As MyType 'do stuff End Using End using will the automatically call the **.Close()** and **.Dispose()**

Comment: Oh so USING is just the same but it has different structure and will call .Close() and .Dispose() automatically, okay thanks anyway. I've resolved the problem just now :D

Comment: @BidiAjin Yes more or less [check here the behavior paragraph](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Okay so now I resolve that the problem is located in `Load(DataTable)`

Welp, I've changed my mind and switch it to `DataSet` instead of `DataTable`.

Thanks for answering my question. Have a good day.

Oh, and here is the working code

```
Using theEditCheckBranchManagerDataReader As SqlDataReader = theEditCheckBranchManagerCommand.ExecuteReader()
        If theEditCheckBranchManagerDataReader.Read() Then
            theEditCheckBranchManagerCommand.Dispose()
            theEditCheckBranchManagerDataReader.Close()
            theEditCheckBranchManagerDataReader.Dispose()
            theConnection.Close()
            SqlConnection.ClearPool(theConnection)

            Dim theEditInputBranchManagerCommand As New SqlCommand
            Dim theEditInputBranchManagerDataSet As New DataSet
            Dim theEditInputBranchManagerDataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter

            theEditInputBranchManagerCommand.Connection = theConnection
            theEditInputBranchManagerCommand.CommandText = "SELECT EmployeeID FROM AssignmentDetail WHERE BranchID = '" & Me.TextBox_BranchID.Text & "'"
            theEditInputBranchManagerDataAdapter.SelectCommand = theEditInputBranchManagerCommand

            theEditInputBranchManagerDataAdapter.Fill(theEditInputBranchManagerDataSet)
            theEditInputBranchManagerDataAdapter.Dispose()
            theEditInputBranchManagerCommand.Dispose()

            Me.ComboBox_BranchManager.DataSource = theEditInputBranchManagerDataSet.Tables(0)
            Me.ComboBox_BranchManager.ValueMember = "EmployeeID"
            Me.ComboBox_BranchManager.DisplayMember = "EmployeeID"
        Else
            theEditCheckBranchManagerCommand.Dispose()
            theEditCheckBranchManagerDataReader.Close()
            theEditCheckBranchManagerDataReader.Dispose()
            theConnection.Close()
            SqlConnection.ClearPool(theConnection)

            Me.ComboBox_BranchManager.DataSource = Nothing
            Me.ComboBox_BranchManager.Items.Clear()
            Me.ComboBox_BranchManager.Text = "-"
        End If
    End Using
```