# Insert multiple rows, count based on another table columns

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have 3 Tables. `Item`, `StockDetail`, `Branch`

I want to INSERT 2 of them at once. The `Item` and `StockDetail` table.

`Item` has 3 columns = `ItemID`, `Title`, `Price`.

`StockDetail` has 3 columns = `ItemID`, `BranchID`, `Stock`.

`Branch` has 1 column = `BranchID`.

In this code below, INSERT into `Item` works fine, but not for `StockDetail` table, it doesn't INSERT anything!

Now for the `StockDetail` if it works, I want to insert it with the condition below:

> If you add an item, then it'll add this item with all existed BranchID.

That mean, every Branches will have this item.

e.g:

You add an item, while

`Branch` has 3 rows of `BranchID` = `BR000`, `BR001`, `BR002`.

It will insert to `StockDetail` with 3 rows as well, at once (single Query)

Complete result of `StockDetail` (single Query):

```
  ItemID | BranchID  | Stock
______________________________
  IM000  |   BR000   |   0
  IM000  |   BR001   |   0
  IM000  |   BR002   |   0
```

---

The Code:

```
'Add function'
'Insert to StockDetail'
Dim theCommand As New SqlCommand
Dim theDataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter
Dim theDataTable As New DataTable
theCommand.Connection = theConnection
theCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO StockDetail VALUES(
                         '" & Me.TextBox_ItemID.Text & "',
                         SELECT COUNT(BranchID) FROM Branch,
                         '0'
                         )"
theDataAdapter.SelectCommand = theCommand
'Insert to Item'
theCommand.Connection = theConnection
theCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Item VALUES('" & Me.TextBox_ItemID.Text & "', '" & Me.TextBox_Title.Text & "', '" & Me.TextBox_Price.Text & "')"
theDataAdapter.SelectCommand = theCommand
theDataAdapter.Fill(theDataTable)
DataGridView_Item.DataSource = theDataTable
theCommand.Dispose()
theDataAdapter.Dispose()
```

UPDATE:

> The code below will tell you the working multiple INSERT, but not with the BranchID INSERT.

```
'Insert to StockDetail'
theConnection.Open()
Dim theCommand As New SqlCommand
Dim theDataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter
theCommand.Connection = theConnection
theCommand.Parameters.Add("@ItemID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Me.TextBox_ItemID.Text
theCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO StockDetail(ItemID, BranchID, Stock) SELECT @ItemID, COUNT(Branch.BranchID), '0' FROM Branch GROUP BY Branch.BranchID"
theDataAdapter.SelectCommand = theCommand
Using theDataAdapter
    theCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    theCommand.Parameters.Clear()
    theCommand.Dispose()
    theConnection.Close()
    SqlConnection.ClearPool(theConnection)
End Using
```

What do I want now?

Well instead of inserting `1`, `1`, . . .

I'd like to INSERT it with `BR000`, `BR001` . . . (Based on all existed `BranchID`)

Comment: Again...you need to parameterize these queries. Continuing to build up strings like this is dangerous and borderline negligent.

Comment: You should also get in the habit of specifying the columns you want to insert or your code is highly brittle. When the table changes, your query is broken.

Comment: @SeanLange wtf, I don't understand about parameterize. I have no idea btw lol

Comment: Did you look at the link I posted in your last question? Have you tried looking at google? I will post an example for you.

Comment: No way, that site seems suspicious! It looking like a scam, lol

Comment: Then try some basic analysis. This seems to have a number of examples from sites that perhaps you aren't scared to use. https://www.google.com/#q=dot+net+parameterized+sql

Comment: Alright, thanks anyway. Hm I'm still a rookie, nope, I'm a volunteer.

Comment: Since you seem nervous to open the site how about just the image which is the basis of that site? https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/exploits_of_a_mom.png

Comment: I think I'm gettin to your "Parameterize" mean. It something like `@ItemID` right? Alright, going to use it by my next project.

Comment: @SeanLange Hey!, It's updated! Your code works but I need other helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you use a parameter in your first insert statement. I think you still have some very serious logic issues here though. This is going to insert 1 row into StockDetail and the values don't make any sense at all. You would be inserting the count of rows from the Branch table as the BranchID which is probably not what you really want. I suspect what you want is a row in this table for each Branch?

```
theCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO StockDetail(ItemID, BranchID, Price) VALUES(
                         @ItemID,
                         (SELECT COUNT(BranchID) FROM Branch),
                         0
                         )"
theCommand.Parameters.Add("@ItemID", SqlDbType.Varchar).Value = Me.TextBox_ItemID.Text;
```

I suspect what you really want is something more like this.

```
theCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO StockDetail(ItemID, BranchID, Price) 
                        select @ItemID
                            , BranchID
                            , 0
                        from Branch";
theCommand.Parameter.Add("@ItemID", SqlDbType.Varchar).Value = Me.TextBox_ItemID.Text;
```

Comment: wtf `StockDetail` has no `Title` and `Price`!
Read the question again lol, I did mention the Columns for each table.

Comment: If you would post your tables as something we can use instead of guessing it wouldn't be so bad. You seem to want a 100% perfectly coded solution but not willing to put in much effort. It doesn't take a huge leap to see it was a typo based on the fact that I am creating code out of thin air.

Comment: And seriously...stop with the wtf nonsense and try to keep things professional.

Comment: Okay okay sorry for the rude conversation. I'll try these things out and I'll give ya result.

Comment: Wait, how can I take `ItemID` from `Branch`?
`SELECT ItemID, BranchID, 0 FROM Branch`.

`Branch` has only 1 columns.

Comment: In this example it using the parameter as the value for ItemID. It doesn't have to exist in the table because it is just a value in a derived column. Try out the query without it being an insert and you will see what I mean.

Comment: Yes yes I've defined the parameters.
But still, it didn't work.

Comment: `StockDetail` still hasn't Inserted yet.

Comment: That is because in your sample you don't ever call the method to actually run the statement. ExecuteNonQuery

Answer (score 0):

The SQL command text for the insert into StockDetail doesn't do what you say you want to happen. This code, though syntactically incorrect (if you want to use a SELECT as a value, you need to surround it in parentheses like this:

```
theCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO StockDetail VALUES(
                         '" & Me.TextBox_ItemID.Text & "',
                         (SELECT COUNT(BranchID) FROM Branch),
                         '0'
                         )"
```

), would insert your ID, a count of the number of branches you have, and a zero into the table.

For what you say you want to have happen, your code would look more like this:

```
theCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO StockDetail SELECT 
                         '" & Me.TextBox_ItemID.Text & "',
                         BranchID, '0' FROM Branch
                         )"
```

Comment: I can't give this a +1 because it is wide open to sql injection.

Comment: why would `ItemID` and `0` is taken from Branch? Didn't you read that Branch has only 1 column, `BranchID`.

Comment: You can select constants in your SELECT statements.

Comment: Tested it, didn't work. Right away, I'm going to sleep first.